# SQL - ALL, Including all values

Tags: sql, sap-iq

I have two tables:

```
create table xyz
(campaign_id varchar(10)
,account_number varchar)

Insert into xyz
values ( 'A', '1'), ('A', '5'), ('A', '7'), ('A', '9'), ('A', '10'),
       ( 'B', '2'), ('B', '3'),
       ( 'C', '1'), ('C', '2'), ('C', '3'), ('C', '5'), ('C', '13'), ('C', '15'),
       ('D', '2'), ('D', '9'), ('D', '10')


create table abc
(account_number varchar)

insert into abc
values ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('5')
```

Now, I want to write a query where all the four account_number `1, 2, 3, 5` are included in a `Campaign_id`.

The answer is C.

[My aim is to find the Campaign Code that includes account_number 1, 2, 3 & 5. This condition is only satisfied by campaign code C.]

I tried using `IN` and `ALL`, but don't work. Could you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after is a inner join. Not sure from your questions which way around you want your data. However this should give you a good clue how to procede and what keywords to lock for in the documentation to go further.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM xyz a
INNER JOIN abc b ON b.account_number = a.account_number;
```

EDIT:

Seems I misunderstood the original question.. sorry. To get what you want you can just do:

```
SELECT  campaign_id
FROM    xyz 
WHERE   account_number IN ('1', '2', '3', '5')
GROUP BY campaign_id
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT account_number) = 4;
```

This is called relational division if you want to investigate further.

Comment: This will list the campaigns that have any of the account numbers in `abc`, not just the ones that have _all_ the account numbers.

Comment: misunderstood the question I guess, sounded to me like he just wanted to find the joins. From your answer my assumption was wrong.

Comment: Sorry, if I sounded confusing. My aim is to find the Campaign Code that includes account_number 1, 2, 3 & 5. This condition is only satisfied by campaign code C. I don't know how to write a query for it.

Comment: @M.Scherzer That's why we like posters to provide the desired output, it helps clarify things like this. He said that the expected result was just `C`, but your query returns `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`.

Comment: yeah got that I ammended my anwser with the correct SQL which I think is nice and concise, no need for any joins.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT campaign_id
FROM (
    SELECT campaign_id, COUNT(*) AS c, total_accounts
    FROM xyz
    JOIN abc ON xyz.account_number = abc.account_number
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_accounts
                FROM abc) AS x
    GROUP BY campaign_id
    HAVING c = total_accounts) AS subq
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff0e8/3)

Comment: Thank you for this, Barmer. It is giving me a strange result though. It gives two blank columns. One Campaign_id, the other is C.

Comment: I've modified the query to just return the `campaign_id` column by moving all the work into a subquery.

Comment: It clearly works in MySQL, as the demo shows. If you're using a different DBMS, you may have to tweak the syntax.

Comment: Please tag your questions with the DBMS you use, to ensure that you get appropriate answers.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sybase, so I don't know how its syntax differs. It's also not available on sqlfiddle.com, so I can't even test my answer with it. You'll have to get further help from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
select xyz.campaign_id
from xyz
join abc
on xyz.account_number = abc.account_number
group by xyz.campaign_id
having count(xyz.campaign_id) = 
(select count(account_number) from abc);
```

**Caution: t-sql implementation**

Comment: Giving blank Campaign_id

Comment: oops! Didn't notice it was sybase iq. My implementation was in t-sql.

Comment: Try to flesh out your answer a bit more. Just posting a code block without any explanation or context is not good.